# "Object has no attribute" bug on one computer, bot not on the other one

Tags: python, opencv, tf.keras

I am coding a program which uses a Keras model downloaded from Internet (not my own) to recognize hand movements. It's working very well on my laptop, and I have absolutely 0 issue. However, I tried running the same program on my desktop PC, using the exact same Python version (Python 3.8) and with the same Python modules installed, and it crashed. Here's the error message I get :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/user/GitHub_Repos/H22-GR10-ReconnaissanceMouvement/Main.py", line 41, in <module>
    frame= calculsEtAnalyse(frame, listeMarqueurs)
  File "C:/Users/user/GitHub_Repos/H22-GR10-ReconnaissanceMouvement/Main.py", line 32, in calculsEtAnalyse
    handProcessor.predictionGeste(listeMarqueurs)
  File "C:\Users\user\GitHub_Repos\H22-GR10-ReconnaissanceMouvement\HandTracker.py", line 46, in predictionGeste
    prediction = handGestureModel.predict([listeMarqueurs])
AttributeError: '_UserObject' object has no attribute 'predict'
[ WARN:0@16.459] global D:\a\opencv-python\opencv-python\opencv\modules\videoio\src\cap_msmf.cpp (539) `anonymous-namespace'::SourceReaderCB::~SourceReaderCB terminating async callback
```

It seems to indicate that my *handGestureModel* object doesn't have the *.predict* command. Here's the "problematic" code :

```
    handGestureModel = load_model('hand_gesture_dataset')
    def predictionGeste(self, listeMarqueurs):
        prediction = handGestureModel.predict([listeMarqueurs])
        IDGeste = np.argmax(prediction)
        nomGeste = handGestureNames[IDGeste]
        if(nomGeste != self.pastNomGeste):
            print(nomGeste)
            self.pastNomGeste = nomGeste
```

I'm not quite sure what to do because, as I've mentionned, this exact same code works flawlessly on my laptop, with the same Python version and the same modules installed. I even re-cloned my GitHub backup to make sure I hadn't broken something on my desktop.

Comment: In both environments, show us the output of `print(type(handGestureModel))`

Comment: You have the same python version, but for sure you do not have the same keras and tensorflow versions, which explains the difference.

Comment: @JohnGordon when I print the type of handGestureModel on my desktop (the one the program doesn't work on), it returns the following : <class 'tensorflow.python.saved_model.load.Loader._recreate_base_user_object.<locals>._UserObject'>

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy I am running Python 3.8 with Keras 2.8.0 and TensorFlow 2.8.0 on both machines, that's why I don't really understand why it doesn't work out on both my PCs